# Subnav <li> to be 100% and position change of dropdown

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to customize using CSS a nav bar but am having issues figuring out how to get the sub menu's to be 100% in width. Currently it seems fixed. I'm also trying to figure out how to get the submenu to be displayed on either side of the dropdown menu, when there is not enough space to show the entire

information. Currently they all show up on the right-hand side of the menu regardless of the size of the submenu.

[image]

I've tried adding various position: and display: tags within the CSS.

Navbar code:

```
<!-- Top menu -->
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- Brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://cronkflies.com"><img src="http://cronkflies.com/img/logo_2019_c_sm.png" alt="cronkflies.com logo"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Home
                        </a>

                    </li>

                   <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">
                            <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $lang_m_stats_2019  ?> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><form class="px-4 py-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <a href="#"><?php echo $lang_m_stats_year ?></a><br />
                                  <select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control form-control-sm" width="100px" name="jaar" id="urlSelect" onchange="window.location = jQuery('#urlSelect option:selected').val();">
                                      <option>--Select--</option>
                                       <?php
                                                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connections/mysqli.php');

                                                $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT YEAR(vertrekdatum2) AS year FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens GROUP BY YEAR(vertrekdatum2) ORDER BY YEAR(vertrekdatum2) DESC ");
                                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                                {
                                                    $j = $row['year'];
                                                    echo "<option value='/stats/jaar/index.php?id=$j&lang=$lang'>$j</option>";                    
                                                }mysqli_close($link);
                                                ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <script>
                                        $(function(){
                                          // bind change event to select
                                          $('#dynamic_select').bind('change', function () {
                                              var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
                                              if (url) { // require a URL
                                                  window.location = url; // redirect
                                              }
                                              return false;
                                          });
                                        });
                                    </script>

                                </div>
                            </form></li>
                            <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/lvm/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airline ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Airport Stats -->
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"><?php echo $lang_m_airport ?></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="hover"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_all ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/luchthavensbijland.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_land ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/aankomstcount.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_a ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/vertrekcount.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_d ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/luchthavensbij_lengte-breedtegraad.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_ll ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/luchthavens/luchthavensbij_hoogte.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_airport_alt ?></a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <!-- General Stats -->
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"><?php echo $lang_m_general ?></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/overige/vluchtbijtoestel.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_general_aar1 ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/overige/vluchtbijtoestel_lvm.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_general_aar2 ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/overige/vluchtbijtoestel_lvm_2.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_general_aar3 ?></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/stats/jaar/mijl_vlucht.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_general_mfc ?></a></li>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/msp/vlucht.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>">MSP Heavy / Int'l Flights</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>    
                </ul>

                </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="/data/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i><br><?php echo $lang_m_flight_list ?></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">
                            <i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $lang_m_photos ?> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/gallery/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_photos_gallery ?></a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/gallery/stats/index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_photos_stats ?></a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/gallery/top_40.php?lang=<?php echo $lang ?>"><?php echo $lang_m_photos_top40 ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
/***** Top menu *****/

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.navbar-nav li a { padding: 23px 20px; background: #fff; border-top: 5px solid #fff; color: #5d5d5d; }
ul.navbar-nav li.active a { background: #f8f8f8; border-color: #3d5199; color: #5d5d5d; }

ul.navbar-nav li a:hover, ul.navbar-nav li a:focus { background: #3d5199; border-color: #3d5199; color: #fff; outline: 0; }

.nav .open > a { background: #f8f8f8; border-color: #3d5199; color: #5d5d5d; }
.nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus { background: #3d5199; border-color: #3d5199; color: #fff; }

ul.navbar-nav li a i { line-height: 35px; color: #aaa; }
ul.navbar-nav li a:hover i, ul.navbar-nav li a:focus i { color: #fff; }

.dropdown-menu {
    border: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15); box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a { background: #fff; color: #5d5d5d; }
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus { background: #f8f8f8; color: #3d5199; }

ul.navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu a { padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu a { background: #fff; color: #5d5d5d; border: 0; }
ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu a:hover, 
ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu a:focus { background: #3d5199; color: #fff; border: 0; }

ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu > .active > a { background: #f8f8f8; color: #3d5199; border: 0; }
ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, 
ul.navbar-nav li.active .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus { background: #3d5199; color: #fff; border: 0; }

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand { margin-left: 0; }

.navbar-brand {
    /*** width: 167px; ***/
    /*** height: 106px; ***/
    background: url(../img/logo.png) left center no-repeat;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}


.dropdown-submenu {position:block;}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
top:0;
left:100%;
margin-top:-6px;
border-bottom: 3px;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
list-style:none;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
margin-top: 10px;
border-bottom: 3px;
color: transparent;
display:block;
width:100%;
} 

/* rotate caret on hover */
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover:after {
transform: rotate(-90deg);
width:100%;
}
```

Current test page that can be viewed for live info is:
http://cronkflies.com/test2.php Flight Stats menu.

Hoping to get 
1. The submenu's to be 100% of text
2. If there is not enough window on the right- switch the submenu to the left side of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove relative positioning from a few places.

[image]

Next, change `left: auto` to `left: 0` on the hidden sub-menus:

[image]

After that, you should see a full-width sub-menu on hover.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Unfortunately this did not work exactly as I thought it would. It made the dropdown the entire size of the page. I abandoned this code for now, as I realized that the template I had gotten was for Bootstrap 3.4 and my pages had already been written in 4.0 and the changes caused negative affects. I appreciate the help, though.